# What is the probability of the dog to reach town A within a day (Word Problem)

Tags: probability, problem-solving, word-problem

A long and narrow railed bridge is situated between town A(to the east) and town B(to the west). A dog is placed at the center of the bridge and it can move about **randomly** across the bridge. Based on thousands of this same experiment conducted in the past, it is concluded that the probability of any dog placed at the center of the bridge to reach town A is 10% **within a day** and there is also a 10% chance that any dog placed at the center of the bridge would reach town B ***within a day***. Therefore, the 4 possible outcomes of the experiments are that the dog could reach: Town A, town B, neither or both towns ***within a day***.

What is the probability of the dog to:

**(i).** Reach town A within a day **and**,

**(ii).** Town B must **not** be reached prior to the occurrence **(i)** above.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates to the *content* of your question.  Also, show your work.  And why does your posting start with "Edit"?

Comment: Noted. @David G. Stork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does not quite have enough details to answer properly, so I'm going to make some assumptions. Namely, I will assume that the dog reaching town $A$ does not affect the probability of whether or not it reaches town $B$ that same day, and vice versa. Moreover, I am assuming that once a dog reaches a town, it does not go back to it directly afterwards (e.g. the dog reaches town $B$, leaves, then goes back to town $B$.)

Let $A$ be the event that the dog reaches town $A$. Let $B$ the event that it reaches town $B$. The only possible things that could happen are:

1. The dog does not reach either town.
2. The dog reaches $A$ and not $B$.
3. The dog reaches $B$ and not $A$.
4. The dog reaches $A$, then goes to $B$.
5. The dog reaches $B$, then goes to $A$.

What are the probabilities of each of these?

1. $P(\lnot A\land\lnot B)=P(\lnot A)P(\lnot B)=0.9\cdot0.9=0.81$.
2. $P(A\land\lnot B)=P(A)P(\lnot B)=0.1\cdot0.9=0.09$.
3. $P(\lnot A\land B)=P(\lnot A)P(B)=0.9\cdot0.1=0.09$.
4. $\frac12P(A\land B)=\frac12P(A)P(B)=\frac12\cdot0.1\cdot0.1=0.005$.
5. $\frac12P(A\land B)=\frac12P(A)P(B)=\frac12\cdot0.1\cdot0.1=0.005$.

To get 4 and 5, note that the event of reaching both towns, $A\land B$, can happen in two ways, each of equal probability.

Hence, we want to know what is the probability of 2 or 4 happening, which is $0.09+0.005=0.095$.

Comment: This answer is a thing of beauty. Well explained. Thank you @Bonnaduck

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have enough rep to upvote but thanks again. Just to be clear, it would be impossible to solve the question if the first assumption is not made right(i.e reaching A does not affect B)? @Bonnaduck

Comment: @StrangePlaces If we don't assume independence, then it cannot be answered with the given information. This could be fixed by adding the condition, for example, that if the dog reaches town $A$, then there is only a $5$% chance that it will reach town $B$ the same day.

Comment: Aaah. I got it now. But if it’s 5% I would still use the same formulas( 2 + 4) but with the new probability, right? @Bonnaduck

Comment: @StrangePlaces No, unfortunately not. If $A$ and $B$ are not independent, then $P(A\land B)=P(A)P(B|A)$, where $P(B|A)$ is the conditional probability "the probability that $B$ occurs given that $A$ has occurred".